Complex complex number proof
My textbook has the following problem:

If $ x - iy  = \sqrt{\frac{a - ib}{c - id}} $, prove that $ (x^2 + y^2)^2 = \frac{a^2 + b^2}{c^2 + d^2} $

My approach was to square both sides of the equality given, and then to multiply and divide the expression on the right-hand side by the conjugate of the denominator to get:

$$ x^2 - y^2 - 2ixy = \frac{ac + bd}{c^2 + d^2} + i \cdot \frac{ad - bc}{c^2 + d^2} $$

I'm stuck from here. I surfed the Internet for solutions, and found this. However, I don't understand how they got the expression for $ x + iy $.

The procedure in the link is incorrect, you can't just "replace $i$ by $-i$". Have you heard of the conjugate of a complex number?

@jjagmath I have indeed. As a matter of fact, I've mentioned multiplying and dividing by the conjugate in the post itself.

Then see my answer.

The foundation of the attack on this problem is that (using $~\overline{z}~$ to represent the conjugate of $~z)~$ $$\overline{z_1} \times \overline{z_2} = \overline{z_1 \times z_2},$$ which is easily proven.  One of the consequences is that $$\frac{\overline{z_1}}{\overline{z_2}} = \overline{~~\left[ ~\frac{z_1}{z_2} ~\right] ~~}.$$

We have
$$(x-i y)^2 = \frac{a-i b}{c-i d}$$
Conjugate to get
$$(x+i y)^2 = \frac{a+i b}{c+i d}$$
Now multiply both expressions and you're done.
Note: This assumes that $x,y,a,b,c,d$ are real numbers. Otherwise, the statement is false.

Well, I feel stupid now. Thank you very much.

Did you mean $(x\color{red}-i y)^2 = \dfrac{a-i b}{c-i d}$?  (The overall answer is still correct)

@J.W.Tanner Yes, thank you.

Here's another approach.  $$\vert x-iy \vert^2=x^2+y^2, \text{ so } \vert (x-iy)^2 \vert^2=(x^2+y^2)^2$$
$$(x-iy)^2= \frac{a-ib}{c-id}, \text{ and }\left \vert \frac{a-ib}{c-id} \right \vert^2 = \frac {a^2+b^2}{c^2+d^2}$$
